# Inserir mais de um registro em uma tabela

Tags: php

Atualmente, estou seguindo as etapas da [fonte oficial do api.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts)

E no estado atual do projeto, estou recebendo informações da tabela, alterando e inserindo dados, sem erros.

No entanto, gostaria de fazer uma inserção em massa na minha tabela.

Esse é o meu código

```
$array = array();
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    array_push(
        $array,
        "('".$object->lat.",".$object->lng."','".$object->other->lat.",".$object->other->lng."')"
    );
}
$values = implode(",", $array);
$client = new Google_Client();
$tableId = "TableId";
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables');
$service = new Google_Service_Fusiontables($client);

$service->query->sql("INSERT INTO ".$tableId." ('Location', 'City Location') VALUES ".$values); // I'm sorry, I forgot.
```

Quando eu tento inserir apenas um registro com o mesmo código, funciona

Essa é a minha váriavel `sql` quando possui mais de um registro:

```
INSERT INTO TableId 
('Location', 'City Location') 
VALUES 
('88.064342,-50.280747','-8.77,-36.62'),
(-55.781345,-69.294770','-28.24,-48.67'),
('14.696452,-26.844802','-19.92,-43.17')
```

A api retorna o seguinte erro:

```
{  
  "error":{  
    "errors":[  
      {  
        "domain":"fusiontables",
        "reason":"badQueryCouldNotParse",
        "message":"Invalid query: Parse error near ',' (line 1, position 92).",
        "locationType":"parameter",
        "location":"q"
      }
    ],
    "code":400,
    "message":"Invalid query: Parse error near ',' (line 1, position 92)."
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual é posição 92? não sei se foi erro na hora de colocar na pergunta mas faltou um aspa simples aqui (segunda linha) `(-55.781345,-69.294770'`

Comment: Foi erro na hora de colocar na pergunta, acabei de achar a referencia de como inserir multiplas colunas: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#insertRow, A sintaxe do SQL é outra

Comment: Então seria só repetir o cabeçalho do insert e separar cada instrução por ponto e vírgula?

Comment: Responde lá acho que é uma boa referência. Falar do  o `import` para muitos inserts também é uma opção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sintaxe para inserir mais de um registro no google fusion API é outra, como pode ser visto em:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#insertRow

### INSERT

Para inserir uma ou mais linhas, a sintaxe `HTTP POST request SQL` é a seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO table_id (nome_coluna, nome_coluna2, nome_coluna3) VALUES (valor1, valor2, valor3);
INSERT INTO table_id (nome_coluna, nome_coluna2, nome_coluna3) VALUES (valor1, valor2, valor3);
.
.
.
INSERT INTO table_id (nome_coluna, nome_coluna2, nome_coluna3) VALUES (valor1, valor2, valor3);
```

---

Vale notar que essa sintaxe vale somente para 500 registros, então você pode fazer um loop no seu objeto e inserir de 500 em 500.

O meu código para inserir, de 500 em 500, usando o Laravel ficou assim:

```
/* 
Esse método pega de 500 em 500 registros, no caso de a tabela ter uma grande quantidade 
de registros, é a mais viável
*/
$objects = Model::with('other')->chunk(500, function ($objects) { 

    $tableId = "tableId";
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$tableId.'` 
        (`Location`, `Other Location`) 
        VALUES 
        ("'.$object->lat.",".$object->lng.'","'.$object->other->lat.",".$object->other->lng.'");';
    }

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables');
    $service = new Google_Service_Fusiontables($client);
    $service->query->sql($sql);
    sleep(2); // Para dar um tempo ao web service e não sobrecarregar
});
```

O tamanho total dos dados de um pedido não deve exceder 1MB e o número total de células da tabela que está sendo adicionado não deve exceder 10.000.

Para eludir melhor o que é uma célula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, não adianta querer adicionar um statement com 500 colunas, o máximo de statments que você teria permissão é 20.

Se você deseja inserir um número excessivo de linhas, o mais indicado é usar o método import, que será mais rápido e mais confiável do que o uso de muitas instruções SQL INSERT.

---

Mesmo depois de seguir as observações e requisitos da documentação, notei que a inserção de dados estava além de muito lenta, retornando muito erro de api, indicando que o servidor está "busy". Então parti para a segunda opção, de usar o método `importRows`.

Minha tabela tem a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para obter o arquivo csv que ira ser importado eu usei o painel administrativo do phpmyadmin. Utilizei o seguinte sql para montar a consulta:

```
SELECT
    '' AS `Text`,
    '' AS `Number`,
    CONCAT(object.lat, ",", object.lng) AS `Location`,
    '' AS `Date`,
    CONCAT(other.lat, ",", other.lng) AS `City Location`
FROM
    `ads`
INNER JOIN cities ON object.city_id = other.id
```

Irei inserir o passo a passo que segui até obter o csv necessário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso eu coloquei o arquivo gerado em um local acessível pelo meu servidor e executei o seguinte código:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables');
$service = new Google_Service_Fusiontables($client);
$tableId = "tabelId";
$service->table->importRows(
    $tableId, 
    array(
        'data' => file_get_contents('objects.csv'), 
        'uploadType' => 'media',
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream'
    )
);
```

E VOILA! **100.000** registros inseridos no fusion table com sucesso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Pode ser feito inserção em massa, através do uso do UNION ALL da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO TableId ('Location', 'City Location')  
SELECT '88.064342,-50.280747','-8.77,-36.62'   
UNION ALL 
SELECT '-55.781345,-69.294770','-28.24,-48.67' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '14.696452,-26.844802','-19.92,-43.17'
```

Comment: Isso no google_fusion_api?